# How to add preprompt in langchain agent?

Tags: typescript, chatbot, langchain

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhpIk.png)

I'm using agent executor with memory but it is answering a very long and complicated answer. I want it short and simple.
that's why I want that my bot answers my question according to some preprompt.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kQRm.png)
Simple hii message is very complicated and it just want it in 2 lines.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.